# when and how consumers of a rabbitmq queue dies?

Tags: rabbitmq

when and how consumers of a rabbitmq queue dies?

We have a rabbitmq queue with minimum consumers of 2 should be alive at all the times.
These consumers increases gradually with increase load/traffic and comes down slowly back to minimum threshold level of 2 consumers when load/traffic decreases.

But some times when the app is running for a while without any restart and perhaps under increased load/traffic those minimum threshold level of consumers of the queue also dies and no. of alive consumers of the queue becomes zero(0) and messages gets stuck in the queue.

We are having to restart the application to bring back those consumers and normalcy resumes afterwards.

We are using below rabbitmq version of the binami helm charts [rabbitmq-chart-link](https://bitnami.com/stack/rabbitmq/helm)

```
RabbitMQ 3.11.2 version
```

So our query is when and how consumers of rabbitmq queue dies and becomes zero and what we need to do to ensure long-lived consumers of the queue?